# Windows XP virtual machine crashes installing driver for host-mapped Velleman K8090 USB relay card

Tags: linux-mint, windows, usb, qemu

I have an existing Windows XP (Win32) virtual machine running under Qemu 1.5.0 on Linux Mint 16. I wanted to test [Velleman 8 channel USB relay card](http://www.velleman.eu/support/downloads/?code=K8090). There is a generic driver available, which I successfully tested on Windows 8 and Windows XP but on physical hardware.

With Qemu I thought I could use Host USB device mapping. The new device is indeed detected by XP but it crashes the VM as soon as the driver is installed.

Is there a[nother] way I can use the relay card in a virtual machine?

---

**EDIT** : On the host the card USB interface is detected as `/dev/ttyACM0`:

```
[567943.203449] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=10cf, idProduct=8090
[567943.203456] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[567943.204152] cdc_acm 3-1:1.0: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[567943.204205] cdc_acm 3-1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually more than one way to use the card: either through USB host mapping or serial port mapping. The former fails and makes the virtual machine crash in a BSOD. The latter seems to work. So I added `/dev/ttyACM0` as a serial port of type *device* to the virtual machine, which was consequently mapped as `COM1` (may vary if serial ports are already present). I then ran the card test application and it could successfully connect and toggle relays on and off.